# extJS tabs not displaying in portal layout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have been trying to build a window with tabs in the portal layout similar to this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/portal/portal.html. The window, top bar, footer, label, combo box and chart everthing is appearing fine but when i place tabs in the window, they dont get displayed. Below is my code

```
 //portal.js that is calling
Ext.define('Ext.app.Portal', {

extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

uses: ['Ext.app.PortalPanel', 'Ext.app.PortalColumn', 'Ext.app.RegHosts', 'Ext.app.ChartPortlet', 'Ext.app.RougeHosts'],

getTools: function(){
    return [{
        xtype: 'tool',
        type: 'gear',
        handler: function(e, target, panelHeader, tool){
            var portlet = panelHeader.ownerCt;
            portlet.setLoading('Working...');
            Ext.defer(function() {
                portlet.setLoading(false);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }];
},

initComponent: function(){
    var content = '<div class="portlet-content">'+Ext.example.shortBogusMarkup+'</div>';

    Ext.apply(this, {
        id: 'app-viewport',
        layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: '0 5 5 5' // pad the layout from the window edges
        },

        items: [{
            id: 'app-header-complete',
            xtype: 'box',
            region: 'north',
            height: 40,
            html: ''
        },{
            xtype: 'container',
            region: 'center',
            layout: 'border',
            items: [{
                id: 'app-portal',
                xtype: 'portalpanel',
                region: 'center',
                items: [{
                    id: 'col-1',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'regehosts',

                        title: 'Registered Hosts',
                        tools: this.getTools(),
                        items: Ext.create('Ext.app.RegeHosts'),
                        listeners: {
                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                        }
                    }]
                },{
                    id: 'col-2',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'rouge',
                        title: 'Rouge Hosts',
                        tools: this.getTools(),
                        items: Ext.create('Ext.app.Rouge'),
                        listeners: {
                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                    id: 'col-3',
                    items: [{
                        id: 'devices',
                        title: 'Devices',
                        tools: this.getTools(),
                        items: Ext.create('Ext.app.Devices'),
                        listeners: {
                            'close': Ext.bind(this.onPortletClose, this)
                        }
                    }]
                }
                ]
            }]
        }]
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onPortletClose: function(portlet) {
    this.showMsg('"' + portlet.title + '" was removed');
},

showMsg: function(msg) {
    var el = Ext.get('app-msg'),
        msgId = Ext.id();

    this.msgId = msgId;
    el.update(msg).show();

    Ext.defer(this.clearMsg, 3000, this, [msgId]);
},

clearMsg: function(msgId) {
    if (msgId === this.msgId) {
        Ext.get('app-msg').hide();
    }
}
});













  // function contents that is called

 requires:["*"],



    ,initComponent:function()
     {Ext.apply(this,{layout: {
        type: 'fit'
     }
     ,width:550,height:420,items:
    [

     {xtype:"label",fieldLabel: text, name:'txt',text:text,    
       id:'devicesLabel',style:'width:300px;'},

 {
xtype:'tabpanel',
width: 400,
    height: 400,

    items: [{
    title: 'Foo'
    }, {
    title: 'Bar',
    tabConfig: {
        title: 'Custom Title',
        tooltip: 'A button tooltip'
    }
    }]

}



   ]


  });this.callParent(arguments)}});
```

Comment: If you want people to help you, you could at least take the time to format your code so it's readable.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli sorry for the trouble.I apologize. But i have done that now.

Comment: the xtype is for the parent container is portalpanel

Comment: Also note your code still isn't formatted at all, it's impossible to read without having to correct it & put it an editor.

Comment: hmm it's hard to read your code but fit layout should have one item. You have label and tabpanel that's two

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read the docs for fit layout, the reason it doesn't work is in the first line: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit

You need to use some other kind of layout, for example to make them appear side by side, use hbox. For on top of each other, use vbox. There's several other layouts, you can see examples of them in the layout browser example.

Comment: tried vbox but not getting the result. I am getting the contents of the first tab but the toolbar isn't displayed. I tried to find the title for my tabs in the html tab of firebug but they are not loaded either.Not even the title of a single tab was rendered. Also, if i set activetab:0 the content of second tab is not loaded(got it through html of firebug) and if i set active tab:1 the content for both tabs get loaded but the toolbar and the titles dont. Also i havent seen any error in console.For the record i m including ext-debug-all in my page. Waiting for your help

Comment: This is a very old topic.. but I recently Ran into the same problem.. Exactly the same problem :( I have wandered on this website, sencha forums, etc.. but did not get any answers.. If anyone here knows the answer, please do share the answer.. :| I have to get the TABS displayed.... Thanks :)